# Scipy.stats.chi2_contingency with ndarray - Value error: '...Use a.any() or a.all()'

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

First time trying to work with scipy.stats and python semi-newbie here. My assumption here is I'm making a rookie mistake somewhere.

**What I'm trying to do:**
I'm trying to perform null hypothesis testing to determine if the differences between the two sets of values are statistically significant.

**Steps I've taken to resolve already:**
I'm attempting to run chi2_convergence() on a ndarray (defined as df_q12) created from two different pandas data frames.

1. I've successfully imported both columns into an array. type(df_q12 returns numpy.ndarray). I had a deprecation warning thrown and imported the existing floats as objects initially.
2. Type cast each column individually as float.
3. Checked the min value of both columns and neither has negative values in it.

**Where I'm stuck:**
I then attempt to run chi2_convergence(df_q12) and get the following error message:

*ValueError

Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 sigtest = stats.chi2_contingency(df_q12)
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\contingency.py in chi2_contingency(observed, correction, lambda_)
240     """
241     observed = np.asarray(observed)
--> 242     if np.any(observed < 0):
243         raise ValueError("All values in `observed` must be nonnegative.")
244     if observed.size == 0:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()*

I interpret from this that negative values would be an issue. I've typecast to float and I've confirmed there are no negative values so I assume that a boolean comparison is going on under the hood, which is the reason it's prompting me to use a.any() or a.all(). I have applied .any()/.all() to the array in every way I can think of and when I do I get the same error message. Since all the activity is inside the function I don't see how I can apply a logical _and/_or operator to resolve it and I'm now out of ideas. And coffee.

How do resolve this?

Being new, full data and annotated code below in case I'm doing something stupid somewhere.

*Data from the ndarray aliased to df_q12:
array([array([215811.36, 225530.07, 198267.42, 212516.26, 214254.05, 203358.59,
185023.12, 218425.58, 203910.32, 218905.62, 198133.95, 210755.81,
217819.05, 215047.31, 223369.46, 184474.9 , 193724.65, 211471.7 ,
196466.5 , 185157.72, 204214.55, 208791.87, 213096.85, 199295.44,
210109.32, 216864.2 , 217865.2 , 209027.57, 231139.18, 224672.48,
212031.97, 190574.09, 196383.47, 214437.06, 213451.43, 209158.5 ,
217324.77, 223547.81, 218391.5 , 209772.31, 199517.71, 199899.88,
218308.09, 209584.02, 206407.47, 209863.69, 222782.56, 205026.92,
211615.22, 215430.12, 236084.36, 194735.31, 196401.62, 199751.56,
214891.74, 189130.68, 202165.39, 208227.24, 208584.51, 187923.27,
212769.02, 215161.08, 190107.19, 219669.23, 228868.57, 218216.05,
214708.25, 203174.42, 199287.56, 197240.56, 225266.36, 202952.95,
211353.93, 213024.91, 210971.06, 237316.14, 245105.  , 233726.35,
233663.55, 208038.24, 185707.23, 223872.12, 238016.12, 206233.25,
245762.5 , 199276.53, 202216.61, 233149.8 , 206679.62, 217083.98,
202216.07, 208514.44, 196676.04, 204081.84, 202991.26, 236524.68,
202721.2 , 212364.19, 253608.92, 196824.48, 196309.21, 215462.17,
214923.33, 198840.52, 202418.17, 199493.47, 201700.65, 187565.16,
196278.83, 203459.04, 207296.34, 204711.73, 229842.  , 203028.24,
210975.82, 201944.06, 222522.58, 185604.38, 190387.49, 203510.35,
208293.01, 241088.39, 216568.42, 207284.95, 215908.  , 203660.09,
205022.49, 203325.31, 198320.6 , 229592.76, 209432.3 , 221327.37,
185173.96, 227394.76, 197296.76, 204906.03, 220196.25, 223749.98,
209139.32, 228930.79, 231419.88, 211612.84, 223534.16, 198760.84,
213055.02, 220203.08, 185529.81, 219061.27, 217430.5 , 191437.28,
193588.99, 218124.7 , 220979.33, 227627.72, 226312.22, 216471.28,
217669.23, 250321.77, 253130.94, 231915.91, 221698.88, 219092.63,
232113.38, 224824.39, 216383.29, 227852.07, 243160.26, 216426.9 ,
198603.95, 205203.47, 230278.41, 214063.73, 209010.48, 242938.63,
211539.13, 246268.6 , 213512.97, 217836.91, 232039.52, 240897.94,
221002.06, 220721.17, 240551.92, 231194.61, 237931.49, 202775.38,
230435.72, 222959.62, 219196.06, 220438.88, 231503.77, 260478.33,
242138.01, 218068.18, 230644.57, 218539.5 , 212766.56, 221743.97,
215233.62, 214294.93, 242313.71, 207778.55, 223623.87, 221437.14,
219816.36, 220898.48, 252990.59, 215987.5 , 219522.39, 236243.06,
243591.84, 210403.06, 229204.86, 228168.73, 223612.35, 235486.85,
218922.05, 240538.72, 229733.26, 225141.81, 211771.89, 238522.56,
234850.23, 229487.1 , 212743.47, 244063.73, 243957.9 , 236757.16,
209121.01, 223561.61, 226287.14, 226334.12, 239284.17, 228801.63,
220396.53, 204535.23, 207628.55, 242813.06, 206626.01, 199732.15,
220114.08, 223704.43, 262790.64, 223534.2 , 219013.75, 229389.6 ,
226615.04, 234565.7 , 237857.52, 220101.64, 239134.47, 217945.74,
207683.26, 231132.12, 229692.42, 222283.69, 236102.46, 203685.5 ,
224649.79, 242949.42, 227583.94, 220522.34, 228364.22, 236243.89,
218480.2 , 216292.24, 226805.43, 214215.03, 200064.28, 235923.09,
246692.7 , 208863.99, 209280.3 , 219247.03, 226977.68, 228711.46,
219680.65, 226071.02, 231372.97, 220940.84, 222727.74, 215168.07,
242470.85, 241183.86, 240931.26, 228020.88, 232412.4 , 253114.92,
237577.24, 231782.61, 206544.28, 228057.66, 221477.08, 225481.8 ,
216135.77, 226779.49, 239228.8 , 245837.6 , 225546.38, 214341.81,
264349.6 , 242791.12, 218464.67, 229409.9 , 206801.88, 204993.64,
221880.32, 207089.58, 213704.42, 244621.41, 235936.17, 217698.56,
214316.6 , 226697.67, 199961.42, 218197.46, 229596.24, 234159.29,
218079.62, 220620.04, 226860.16, 215900.76, 219944.54, 234084.71,
232535.91, 224649.17, 242623.98, 234491.04, 212329.69, 229580.12,
230916.34, 211187.35, 230921.9 , 217633.42, 230363.93, 231443.18,
213624.45, 214084.32, 216545.94, 204993.59, 224477.13, 230655.13,
212126.2 , 207097.42, 226887.14, 212966.18, 220846.34, 225769.37,
220022.39, 228391.78, 220948.92, 244534.46, 220923.42, 230347.97,
226019.46, 212332.86, 217921.67, 200995.6 , 221561.12, 223457.42,
223283.63, 240818.85, 222027.19, 218072.98]),
array([220521.  , 214748.51, 237949.89, 207400.21, 244611.05, 228209.38,
218324.13, 229540.33, 198803.13, 220433.84, 225198.16, 212052.5 ,
246100.12, 192098.67, 217977.97, 221215.52, 215292.47, 220573.29,
237701.89, 211221.18, 224769.97, 221269.76, 233120.7 , 222454.6 ,
228400.34, 236253.04, 229907.99, 211246.77, 237713.79, 218905.89,
219064.34, 215867.  , 230245.83, 242801.12, 231355.99, 213356.78,
222108.57, 216522.48, 245615.12, 222268.67, 237731.59, 206498.71,
216644.95, 214307.76, 216306.61, 224300.53, 213143.65, 224560.44,
215974.54, 232083.31, 232898.42, 212865.84, 198008.36, 218043.58,
223685.35, 219866.29, 250600.68, 231075.18, 240588.34, 232340.84,
221697.06, 262814.73, 259422.45, 263809.38, 262658.33, 292085.61,
296326.78, 270356.51, 294678.21, 288563.65, 289814.77, 284764.89,
275944.68, 257262.95, 279310.55, 266544.56, 280197.73, 294567.25,
261627.16, 294270.37, 255809.01, 294406.83, 258482.9 , 286047.36,
296535.81, 297001.64, 261204.46, 285997.7 , 278522.92, 275723.43,
282713.81, 286326.43, 255133.88, 281620.5 , 307878.08, 280177.3 ,
275946.72, 266206.13, 273901.77, 284267.88, 271712.6 , 276743.02,
267725.55, 268090.07, 282362.86, 288993.96, 252626.76, 304787.33,
285556.63, 268903.6 , 267305.66, 273158.34, 279373.  , 248940.02,
292850.45, 293798.12, 280864.57, 271289.4 , 298083.23, 277730.68,
265415.04, 311104.73, 266586.9 , 275110.78, 299955.73, 261285.5 ,
256520.79, 273203.79, 304225.17, 301307.72, 253590.53, 262333.45,
269571.89, 290846.16, 284643.81, 297367.44, 282023.04, 279090.59,
289588.13, 282481.78, 261411.17, 250816.84, 265149.14, 259258.88,
310512.72, 257620.25, 286011.91, 303931.  , 292495.41, 289256.68,
299813.81, 266187.16, 279987.15, 215366.44, 241956.98, 227704.45,
216477.74, 230363.31, 218791.79, 210513.55, 226063.2 , 232533.57,
217075.43, 238669.29, 235908.1 , 217481.39, 231542.11, 194892.86,
208282.25, 246944.02, 221500.85, 227364.29, 222164.66, 227594.51,
214899.22, 239267.56, 219743.7 , 220969.13, 233171.07, 226127.71,
234041.17, 193541.17, 226891.74, 230047.64, 229922.05, 220075.76,
226320.32, 233931.01, 229104.73, 214146.  , 217682.42, 238526.54,
213563.77, 204676.15, 224322.95, 229124.46, 213426.79, 223763.71,
226022.14, 224145.28, 220976.63, 229450.14, 199157.66, 247660.72,
229099.51, 221096.28, 232582.35, 205445.95, 227899.58, 227205.4 ,
202458.72, 223668.08, 222830.76, 231744.24, 222215.3 , 209346.32,
228354.2 , 244410.78, 234203.08, 221032.88, 224545.49, 251254.4 ,
221726.69, 223515.34, 223135.35, 213648.48, 224442.04, 227248.63,
240377.42, 203357.37, 205494.03, 241988.01, 228788.  , 234966.62,
235993.11, 224000.3 , 226601.65, 225616.58, 213258.97, 217105.54,
246740.64, 236386.48, 241388.42, 218093.57, 232212.57, 227998.53,
225645.66, 209959.16, 226746.48, 217287.97, 219516.77, 208008.83,
204576.3 , 222094.2 , 216629.44, 240137.59, 224735.34, 238799.75,
216066.65, 205413.69, 209655.99, 221595.7 , 209092.19, 220330.63,
211108.16, 258312.59, 227245.29, 209126.25, 224846.59, 226452.67,
220224.9 , 211032.47, 220379.49, 211979.39, 223078.69, 224219.36,
234721.26, 222765.24, 214398.97, 217952.16, 235957.47, 216041.13,
215472.68, 282592.89, 245940.81, 221952.67, 219267.44, 235109.63,
218915.66, 236101.74, 220775.75, 227117.6 , 250352.31, 236766.15,
228836.07, 223404.54, 237986.3 , 238206.01, 199580.83, 212679.62,
217286.31, 232515.29, 214405.56, 219631.56, 222934.7 , 219887.33,
244923.9 , 207364.38, 233383.88, 231076.46, 225752.76, 219868.12,
216717.19, 205702.67, 237615.44, 200176.23, 232516.74, 212155.27,
219839.67, 225234.2 , 221428.71, 214874.4 , 219397.58, 215118.51,
226692.06, 239060.01, 230227.72, 217069.31, 222912.52, 225029.83,
200494.97, 212343.25, 220732.44, 230495.64, 256233.35, 222425.35,
208100.89, 231571.11, 227705.47, 217850.45, 230791.23, 243621.41,
205616.34, 220113.64, 239415.  , 213952.62, 236772.42, 212686.94,
220978.53, 234822.43, 228314.68, 221396.67, 214984.84, 226994.38,
228590.63, 224911.11, 223924.48, 214580.72, 231291.3 , 220624.85,
219361.71, 223527.85, 226842.41, 251526.13, 222621.63, 214709.2 ])],
dtype=object)*

```
df_q12 = np.array([df_q11_y1['cost'].values,df_q11_y2['cost'].values],dtype=object)#import from existing pandas dataframes. Successful and reads as numpy.ndarray type when checked.

df_q12[0].astype(float) #typecast column 1 to float
df_q12[1].astype(float) #typecast column 2 to float

sigtest = stats.chi2_contingency(df_q12) #throws error
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem was being created in the array itself, length of first column was 364, length of second column was 366.